# Exchange 2007 - Mailbox Database Recovery

Tags: exchange-2007, disaster-recovery

Exchange 2007 edb

Can we restore Exchange edb (First storage group\mailbox database.edb) to another exchange server ?

Do I just copy the edb to the new exchange server and delete the first storage group\mailbox database.edb and replace it with this one ?

How can I get all the mailboxes from that (old) mailbox database.edb ?

I had a exchange 2007 server with 10 mailboxes, I have installed exchange on another machine and was thinking if I can do the above ? or is there any way I can get all the mailboxes from that edb (old mailbox database) and import them into the new one.

I have deleted the old exchange install I had (these are test machines)

What are the steps required to get the DB working on the new machine ?

Also, I am confused about the recovery storage group ?

I can mount a mailbox database in recovery storage group, but when I try to get mailbox out of it, it won't match any thing ? can someone please assist in understanding RSG and how to restore the OLD mailbox database.

thanks and regards
Phrontiste

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like the [How to Restore a Mailbox Database to a New Server with Database Portability](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998340(EXCHG.80).aspx)
 article would probably be helpful to you. Exchange [database portability](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123954(EXCHG.80).aspx) should help you with matters.

Answer (score 0):

There are some situations when built-in repair utilities do not work. In such cases a third party Exchange database repair software may help the Exchange Server applications. Here is one such popular Exchange tool that helped us in repairing and restoring the Exchange database files successfully: http://www.recover-computerdata.com/exchange-server-recovery.html

This is really very useful application that effectively handles the corruption and data loss situations in database files.

Answer (score 0):

**Recovery Storage group** feature which was very popular with earlier versions of Exchange Server is known as recovery database in Exchange Server 2010 and its later versions. The main concept behind the creation of RSG in Exchange server 2013 is almost the same. Here, the system administrators can mount the database and then extract the data from the database which has been mounted. Let us understand the process of RSG in [details](https://www.mytechlogy.com/IT-blogs/8225/know-how-to-create-recovery-storage-group-exchange-2013/#.XAZ3yWgzaM8) and to restore exchange mailbox, follow the guide mentioned in Microsoft Documentation Evan Anderson solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use Database Portability feature to restore Exchange edb to another Exchange server :

**IMPORTANT POINTS:**

1. You can move into another mailbox for the same organization only
2. The database to be moved should be from the same or newer Exchange Server version.

**Steps:**

1. Create the recovery database on an Exchange server
2. Restore a backup into the recovery database
3. Run one or more mailbox restore requests
4. Remove the recovery database

You can use [this article for detailed steps](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/32807/PowerShell-Commands-to-Restore-Exchange-2007-Mailbox.html).